# What is the name for those tag wrappers for text found in Gmail compose, Facebook invite friends, and of course StackExchange tags?

Tags: multi-selection, data-entry, multiple-data, wrapping

I see this sort of UX element in a lot of places, and pardon my ignorance, but I just don't know what they are called (if they are called anything at all.

It consists of wrapping a text specification in a nice little color wrapper, and usually including a little `X` to remove it. I'm referring to the graphical wrappings of the `TO` email addresses in a Gmail compose window like here

[image: Gmail Compose]

and also, when adding tags to a StackExchange question like here

[image: stack exchange tags]

What is this graphical element called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question, several times!

**They're called tags, or labels.**

That's both the UX term and the term for the look. UX-wise this name was chosen because functionally, they're little labels that can easily be hooked onto certain items/objects, and they illustrate values that relate to said object.

The same goes for the look: they look like little bits of plastic or paper with a label printed onto them!

Comment: Do you have a reference for your answer? I'm trying to Google "tags labels UX design" and similar but I'm not finding what I'm looking for

Comment: That's because UX means "user experience". Since you're looking for a user interface element, look for "Tags UI". You'll find nothing but examples of those. Like literally hundreds :)

Answer (score 0):

They're perhaps most universally referred to as **tags**. You may be interested in [the UI-Patterns page on them.](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Tag)

However there's a wide variety of names for tags. I discovered the following by looking at the code from the websites:

- **mentions** (facebook)
- **tags** (stack exchange)
- **tokens** (pinterest)